# Constrain specific values in Scipy curve fitting

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I have what may be quite a basic question, but a quick googling was not able to solve it.

So I have some experimental data that I need to fit with an equation like

```
a * exp^{-x/t}
```

in the case of needing more components the expression is

```
a * exp^{-x/t1} + b * exp^{-x/t2} ... + n * exp^{-x/tn}
```

for n elements

Right now I have the following code

```
x = np.array([0.0001, 0.0004, 0.0006, 0.0008, 0.001, 0.0015, 0.002, 0.004, 0.006, 0.008, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 1.5, 2, 4, 6, 8])
y1= np.array([5176350.00, 5144208.69, 4998297.04, 4787100.79, 4555731.93, 4030741.17, 3637802.79, 2949911.45, 2816472.26, 2831962.09, 2833262.53, 2815205.34, 2610685.14, 3581566.94, 1820610.74, 2100882.80, 1762737.50, 1558251.40, 997259.21, 977892.00, 518709.91, 309594.88, 186184.52])
y2 = np.array([441983.26, 423371.31, 399370.82, 390603.58, 378351.08, 356511.93, 349582.29, 346425.39, 351191.31, 329363.40, 325154.86, 352906.21, 333150.81, 301613.81, 94043.05, 100885.77, 86193.40, 75548.26, 27958.11, 20262.68, 27945.10])

    def fitcurve (x, a, b, t1, t2): 
        return a * np.exp(- x / t1) + b * np.exp(- x / t2) 
    
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(fitcurve, x, y)
    print('a = ', popt[0], 'b = ', popt[1], 't1 = ', popt[2], 't2 = ', popt[3])
    
    
    plt.plot(x,y, 'bo')
    plt.plot(x,fitcurve(x, *popt))
```

Something important is that a+b+...n = is equal to 1. Basically the percentage of each component. Ideally, I want to plot 1, 2, 3 and 4 components and see which ones provide a better fitting

Comment: In your data y(x) tends to 1 for large x. But in your function (sum of exponentials) y(x) tends to 0 for large x, what ever are the coefficients and what ever is the sum of the coeffticients. What is the mistake ? Moreover your data is not normalized thus why y tends to 1  for large x ? There is something fishy in the wording of the problem.

Comment: Wery well you changed the data. My first answer is no longer valid. But your new data is not consistent. The x array has 23 items while the y2 array has 21 items. Sorry I will not continue to spent time on this question.  I wish you all the best in your research.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that your data cannot be fitted with a simple sum of exponential functions. Did you draw the points on a graph in order to see what is the shape of the curve ?

[image]

This looks more like a function of logistic kind (but not exactly logistic) than a sum of exponentials.

I could provide some advises to fit a sum of exponential (even with condition about the sum of coefficients). But this would be of no use with your data. Of course if you have other data convenient to fit a sum of exponentials, I would be pleased to show how to proceed.

Comment: I just noticed there was something wrong with my data. I've updated the question to the correct data

Comment: I'm importing the data using pandas and as you can see the y2 has some Nan value which then also gives an error when using scipy's fit function

Comment: If your question is about a problem of transfer of data from one software to another I am not qualified.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going into the model-fitting procedure but what you can do is `argparse` variable number of paramters and then try to fit for various numbers of exponentials. You can make use of the broadcasting feature of `numpy` to achieve this.

EDIT: you have to take care of the number of elements in argparse. Only even numbers works now. I leave it up to you to edit that part in (trivial).

## Target

We want to fit $$\sum_i^N a_i \exp(-b_i x)$$ for variable $n$

## Output:

[image]

## Implementation:

```py
from scipy import optimize, ndimage, interpolate
x = np.array([0.0001, 0.0004, 0.0006, 0.0008, 0.0010, 0.0015, 0.0020, 0.0040, 0.0060, 0.0080, 0.0100, 0.0500, 0.1000, 0.2000, 0.5000, 0.6000, 0.8000, 1.0000, 1.5000, 2.0000, 4.0000, 6.0000, 8.0000, 10.0000])
y = np.array([416312.6500, 387276.6400, 364153.7600, 350981.7000, 336813.8800, 314992.6100, 310430.4600, 318255.1700, 318487.1700, 291768.9700, 276617.3000, 305250.2100, 272001.3500, 260540.5600, 173677.1900, 155821.5500, 151502.9700, 83559.9000, 256097.3600, 20761.8400, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000])
# variable args fit
def fitcurve (x, *args): 
    args = np.array(args)
    half = len(args)//2
    y = args[:half] * np.exp(-x[:, None] * args[half:])
    return y.sum(-1)

# data seems to contain outlier?
# y = ndimage.median_filter(y, 5)


popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(fitcurve, x, y,
                                bounds = (0, np.inf),
                                p0     = np.ones(6), # set variable size
                               maxfev = 1e3,
                               )
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y, 'bo')
# ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('symlog')

ax.plot(x,fitcurve(x, *popt))
fig.show()
```